# NDepend says PDB file missing, incorrectly locates release exe instead of debug exe

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ndepend

NDepend newbie here.  I am using the standalone version (VisualNDepend.exe) to analyze a C# solution.

When I choose the solution file, NDepend warns that the assembly PDB file is missing:

[image]

The solution is configured as Debug/x64 and therefore, its associated PDB file is available.

However, I think the real problem is that NDepend is confused about the solution configuration, as it points to the release exe (reported in the final line in the tooltip that it displays) instead of the debug exe.

What am I doing wrong, and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

@Sabuncu, you need to delete the row of the assembly file compiled in RELEASE mode, click the button *Browse*, and select in Windows Explorer the assembly file compiled in DEBUG mode.

Here is the documentation [Understanding NDepend Analysis Inputs](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-analysis-inputs-explanation) that explains why having the DEBUG assembly with PDB is important.